# Producer-Consumer : Parallel Programming

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

my question is really simple : is this program valid as a simulation of the producer-consumer problem ?

```
public class ProducerConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Consumers c = new Consumers(false, null);
         Producer p = new Producer(true, c);
         c.p = p;

         p.start();
         c.start();
    }

}

class Consumers extends Thread {
    boolean hungry; // I want to eat
    Producer p;

    public Consumers(boolean hungry, Producer p) {
        this.hungry = hungry;
        this.p = p;

    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // While the producer want to produce, don't go
            while (p.nice == true) {
              // Simulation of the waiting, to check if it doesn't wait and 
              //`eat at the same time or any bad interleavings
              System.out.println("Consumer doesn't eat");
              try {
                sleep(500);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
                // Because the consumer eat, the producer is boring and
                // want to produce, that's the meaning of the nice.
                // This line makes the producer automatically wait in the
                // while loop as soon as it has finished to produce.
                p.nice = true;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Consumer eat");
        }
        hungry = false;
        System.out.println("\nConsumer doesn't eat anymore\n");
    }
     }
}

class Producer extends Thread {
    boolean nice;
    Consumers c;

    public Producer(boolean nice, Consumers c) {
        this.nice = nice;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            /**
             * I begin with the producer so the producer, doesn't enter the 
             * loop because no food has been produce and hungry is
             * exceptionally false because that's how work this program,
             * so at first time the producer doesn't enter the loop.
             */
             while (c.hungry == true) {
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Producer doesn't produce");
             }

            /**
             * While the consumer wait in the while loop of its run method 
             * which means that nice is true the producer produce and during
             * the production the consumer become hungry, which make the 
             * loop "enterable" for theproducer. The advantage of this is
             * that the producer already knows that it has to go away after 
             * producing, the consumer doesn't need to tell him
             * Produce become true, and it has no effect for the first round
             */
             for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                 try {
                     sleep(1000);
                     c.hungry = true;

                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 System.out.println("Producer produce");
             }

             /**
             * After a while, producer produce, the consumer is still in the 
             * loop, so we can tell him he can go, but we have to make
             * sure that the producer doesn't pass the loop before the 
             * consumer goes out and set back produce to true will lead the
             * consumer to be stuck again, and that's the role of the, 
             * c.hungry in the for loop, because the producer knows it has
             * some client, it directly enter the loop and so can't
             * starve the client.
             */
             System.out.println("\nProducer doesn't produce anymore\n");
             nice = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't use any synchronization, wait or notify, so for a parallel programming problem it seems very strange, but when I run it there aren't any deadlocks, starvation or bad interleavings, the producer produces, then stop, the consumer eats and then stops and again as many time as I wanted.

Have I cheat somewhere ?

Thanks !

P.S- I don't know why but the first line of my question doesn't appear, it was just said hello

Answer (score 0):

First of all, careful with the naming, "Consumers" is misleading, you are only simulating a lone consumer. Nice can also be replaced with "producing".

Secondly, you're using while(condition) sleep, which is basically the less efficient, non protected version of a semaphore wait, so you did use a form of wait.

E.G.

```
while (p.nice == true) {
          System.out.println("Consumer doesn't eat");
          try {
            sleep(500);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
```

is your P()

```
System.out.println("\nProducer doesn't produce anymore\n");
nice = false;
```

is your V()

This method, however is both inefficient (the waiting thread is either busy waiting or sleeps for a moment while being able to go) and unprotected (because there is no protection for simultaneous access of *nice* and *hungry*, you won't be able to expand this program with more Consumers or Producers).

Hope this helps.